# CodeIgniter query returns an empty array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a JOIN query in CodeIgniter which returns an empty array.

My Controller part:

```
if ($this->session->has_userdata('user')) {

    $id = $this->session->user['id'];

    $where = ["products.user_id =" => $id];

    $status = $this->insertModel->get_status($where);

    $this->load->view('profile', ["status" => $status]);
}
```

My model:

```
return $this->db
        ->from('photos')
        ->join('products', 'photos.prod_id = products.id', 'left')
        ->where($where)
        ->get()
        ->result_array();
```

Comment: ok.... and what are you wanting it to return?  What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your controller, just send `$id` instead of `$where`

```
$status = $this->insertModel->get_status($id);
```

and rebuild your where clause in your model the Codeigniter way:

```
->where('products.user_id', $id)
```

see the docs [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

and [about MVC](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/overview/mvc.html) (Model=database interaction, View=browser output and Controller=your application logic)

Answer (score 0):

Controller:
Your error is in $where, check my code

```
if ($this->session->has_userdata('user')) {

    $id = $this->session->user['id'];

    //$where = ["products.user_id =" => $id];//old line
    $where = array("products.user_id" => $id);//new line

    $status = $this->insertModel->get_status($where);

    $this->load->view('profile', ["status" => $status]);
}
```